# In robots.txt, should I use a wildcard at the end of a disallow directive?

Tags: google-search, robots.txt

I want to disallow a specific folder and all of its files and subdirectories but I don't know the difference between `Disallow: /somedir/` and `Disallow: /somedir/*`. which one of these lines should I use?

By the way, what does `Disallow: /somedir?` mean? should I use it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Disallow: /somedir/` and `Disallow: /somedir/*` Both are same, here is what google dev [said about it](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt#url-matching-based-on-path-values).

> /* is Equivalent to /. The trailing wildcard is ignored.

And `Disallow: /somedir?` will block only directory like `/somedir?id=1`, and `/somedir?id=2`.